# Using two NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nstimer

I'm creating this app that converts text to Morse code and then flash it out using the iPhone's flashlight. I have used string replacement to convert the content of a NSString to Morse code. I have found a script that turns the iPhone's flashlight on and off, with adjustable intervals using NSTimer. But I can't figure out how to add two different intervals, one for the morse "." and one for the morse "-". Can anyone help me?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

int spaceTime;
    spaceTime = 1;

int flashTimePrik;
    flashTimePrik = 5;

strobeIsOn = NO;
strobeActivated = NO;
strobeFlashOn = NO;

flashController = [[FlashController alloc] init];

self.strobeTimer =          [
                            NSTimer 
                            scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:spaceTime
                            target:self 
                            selector:@selector(strobeTimerCallback:) 
                            userInfo:nil 
                            repeats:YES
                            ];

self.strobeFlashTimer =     [
                            NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:flashTimePrik 
                            target:self 
                            selector:@selector(strobeFlashTimerCallback:) 
                            userInfo:nil 
                            repeats:YES
                            ];


}
- (void)strobeTimerCallback:(id)sender {
  if (strobeActivated) {
        strobeIsOn = !strobeIsOn;
        strobeFlashOn = YES;

} else {
        strobeFlashOn = NO;
}
}
- (void)strobeFlashTimerCallback:(id)sender {
if (strobeFlashOn) {
    strobeFlashOn = !strobeFlashOn;
    [self startStopStrobe:strobeIsOn];

} else {
    [self startStopStrobe:NO];
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use one timer, set the time interval based on the dot, dash or space interval. For "A" which is dot space dash

- Turn on the light and set that timer to the dot interval.
- When the timer fires, turn the light off and set the timer to the space interval.
- When the timer fires, turn the light on and set the timer to the dash interval.
- When the timer fires, turn the light off.

Answer (score 0):

Use a bajillion timers. All single fire mode. Want an short call call to flash short. Then in the timer call back, create another timer for the next dash or dot. When there are no more signals to transmit in the array, you are done. Code is approximate....

```
 - (void)lightTimerOffCallback:(id)sender {
       turnLIGHTOFF
       [NSTimer scheduledTimer:intervalbeforeStartingNextChar... selector(@startNextDotOrFlash) repeat NO]
  }


 - (void)startNextDotOrFlash:(id)sender {
    if (there is a new dot or dash to do)
      intervalToLeaveThisLightOn = 1.0 : 0.1 ? isDot; 
       turnLIGHTON
       [NSTimer scheduledTimer:intervalToLeaveThisLightOn... selector(@lightTimerOffCallback) repeat NO]
  }
```

Don't need the timer in an iVar.